# C# MVC - Filter results based on eNum value passed in querystring to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

OK, so this should be easy but I am in a pickle.

**MODEL**

```
public enum ItemType
    {
        Article = 1,
        Link = 2,
        Event = 3,
        Training = 4,
        Job = 5
    }

  public class SiteItem 
    {

     public int ID { get; set; }
     public ItemType ItemType { get; set; }
}
```

I want to filter results based on querystring

http://site/Admin/AllItems?type=4

This would return all *Training* items.

**CONTROLLER**

```
public ActionResult AllItems(int? passedItem)
        {
            IQueryable<SiteItem> siteItems;               

                siteItems = db.SiteItems.Include(s => s.ApplicationUser).
                    Include(i => i.TagLinks).
                    Where(x => x.Approved == true);    

                if (passedItem > 0)
                {                   
                    siteItems = siteItems.Where(t => t.ItemType = passedItem);
                }

                siteItems = siteItems.OrderByDescending(a => a.DatePosted);

            return View(siteItems.ToList());          
        }
```

This isn't working. I can't pass an integer value from the querystring to filter the results. In the database the ItemType field has numbers 4,3,5 etc. I just want to match integer to integer.

Hope this all makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

**Old code**

```
siteItems = siteItems.Where(t => t.ItemType = passedItem);
```

You need to type cast the property

**Updated code**

```
 siteItems = siteItems.Where(t => t.ItemType == (ItemType)pass
```

Comment: siteItems = siteItems.Where(t => t.ItemType == (ItemType)passedItem); 
Yes, that works!!! Thanks Prasad. :)

Comment: its my pleasure dr..cheer up